# DNS Hostname RegEx Timeout for particular domains

Tags: regex, dns, hostname

I have

```
^\*|^(\*\.)?((xn\-\-)?_?[a-zA-Z0-9]+([\/\-_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*_?(((\.xn\-\-)|\.)[\-_]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+([\/_\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}){0,})*\_?\.?)?(((xn\-\-)?_?[a-zA-Z0-9]+(((\.xn\-\-)?|[\-\._])[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.)*(xn\-\-)?[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,})?\.?$
```

This regex results in a timeout for the following Hostname:

```
hjksdhfkjshdkjfhsjkdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfs._
```

Can any one please help fixing this issue.

Comment: Already  `([\/\-_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` is wrong, there may be more bottlenecks.

Comment: A DNS name is limited to 255 characters (bytes in fact) in total and up to 63 per labels ("between" two dots), two points not enforced by your expression. Among other problems (for example any case of `^..--` is forbidden outside of `xn--`.  Also `_` is not allowed in hostnames, where you can have `xn--` so you can't have both in the same expression, makes no sense). Also a name (each label) can not start with `-` or end with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
^\*|^(\*\.)?((xn--)?_?[a-zA-Z0-9]+([\/_-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*_?(\.(xn--)?[-_]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+([\/_-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)*_?\.?)?(((xn--)?_?[a-zA-Z0-9]+((\.xn--|[-._])[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.)*(xn--)?[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,})?\.?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bVCmGV/1).

*Notes*:

- `([\/\-_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` is a common error where one part in the quantified group is optional and the other is obligatory, in these cases, check the left-hand context and fix accordingly. Here, since there is a `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` right before, so you need to use `+` instead of `*` inside the quantified group, i.e. ([/_-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*`
- Same thing with `[a-zA-Z0-9]+(((\.xn\-\-)?|[\-\._])[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` where `((\.xn\-\-)?|[\-\._])` is optional, while it must be obligatory
- Escaping hyphens outside of character classes is useless, `xn\-\-` must be replaced wit `xn--`
- `{1,}` - is the same as `+`
- `{0,}` - is the same as `*`.